# Model in simple MVC?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

A quick question, is it ok for the controller to contain a pointer to a model object so that it can use an instance method to alloc and then call the model as needed. Or is it best to set the model up as a singleton and then use a static pointer / class method to access the model as needed. Or either, it simply does not matter?

Just curious as I have used both, one ties the model to the controller, whilst the other leaves the model more independent but means it can be accessed from anywhere?

Cheers gary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly normal for the controller to hold a pointer to the model. After all, interacting with the model is one of its most important jobs. IMO, singletons should be avoided in most cases unless you have a very good reason to use them.

Comment: Perfect, thank you Ole, that was something I have been wanting to clear up for a while, most books just skip over the model aspect of MVC.

Comment: @Joe Blow: I agree singletons are great – if you have a case (such as a class representing a single hardware device). Model classes are usually not such cases IMO.

Comment: The app delegate is not a singleton, though; UIApplication is (sort of; a "true" singleton in ObjC is both tedious and unnecessary). Moreover, `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate` seems to be `nil` while the app is still loading the main nib, which is particularly unhelpful.

Comment: What happens when you get multiple controllers with pointers to the model?